# Application Type

Tags: sql, winapi, mfc, clr

When developing a stand alone application for windows, what type of application should i use.

CLR
MFC
Win32

The application will be connected to an SQL Database, have multible forms, use a Ribbon Bar.

If anyone needs more info to answer this question please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- if you want it .NET, I'd go for a WPF .NET C# application
- if you want native code, then you can do a C++ MFC app (not CLR, as if you can do .NET, you'd be better off with a C# app).   Lots more pain this way, but it will be native code if that is of advantage to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could use http://www.wxwidgets.org/, that is not only a GUI library, but a complete set of APIs (wxNet, wxXML, wxMedia, wxODBC, wxGL et cetera).
For example, you could use wxDbGrid, that lets you simply create a database grid.

Moreover, wxWidgets is crossplatform, so with a little effort you can port your application to Linux or even Mac OS X.

Comment: Does wxWidgets have a ribbon? That was listed as a requirement.